# group product or bundle product?

Tags: magento-1.9, stock, manage-stock

I have product A which is composed of 2 products B and 1 product C.

The user can buy the Product A (so with product A B C ) on a page. The stock is decreased on A B C.

OR

He can separately buy the product B on a separate page. So in this case, we have to recalculate the stock of the Product A.

I don't want to have product B or C as an option on the page of product A. If a user buys product A, its inevitably B + C.

Is it possible to do that with Magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group product because this will show all simple products which are associated with the group product and customer can buy all products by filling up the qty fields separately and then if user click on add to cart then all select qtys with simple products will be added to cart.

Also for separate product purchase dont set visibility to "not visible individually". Just use catalog search for group and simples as well.

Hope this helps